# Link Connectors to ChartPoint VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro that add an arrow to chartPoint if value of that point is under 1  and different from 0
The code works perfectly but When Itry to create The Arrow I get an error "Object Required" and I didn't manage to select the head of that shape and create arrow there .

What I'm trying to do is described in the Image below
[image]

[image]

The code of Verifying Result and Add arrow is below

```
Sub fzerfgsdf()
 '
 '    fzerfgsdf Macro
 '

Dim clLeft As Double
Dim clTop As Double
Dim clWidth As Double
Dim clHeight As Double

Dim cl As Range
Dim shpOval As Shape

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graphique 69").Activate
x = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values
For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
  Debug.Print "Point "; i; "="; x(i)
  If x(i) < 1 And x(i) <> 0 Then
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Select


    Set cl = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Select  '<-- Range("C2")

    clLeft = cl.Left
    clTop = cl.Top
    clHeight = 131.25
    clWidth = 579

    Set shpOval = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, clLeft, clTop, 579, 131.25)
    shpOval.Select
    selection.ShapeRange.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadOpen
    selection.ShapeRange.ShapeStyle = msoLineStylePreset20
  End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I found solution for first problem which is creating shape  but I can't figure out how to locate that shape in the right place where the blue chart using a specific values see image

```
Sub fzerfgsdf()
 '
' fzerfgsdf Macro
 '
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graphique 69").Activate
 x = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values
For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
Debug.Print "Point "; i; "="; x(i)
If x(i) < 1 And x(i) <> 0 Then
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graphique 69").Activate
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Select
Dim clLeft As Double
Dim clTop As Double
Dim clWidth As Double
Dim clHeight As Double

Dim cl As Point
Dim shpOval As Shape

Set cl = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i)  '<-- Range("C2")

clLeft = cl.Left
 clTop = cl.Top
 clHeight = 131.25
 clWidth = 579

  Set shpOval = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 
  clLeft, 
   clTop, 579, 131.25)
   shpOval.Select
   selection.ShapeRange.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadOpen
  selection.ShapeRange.ShapeStyle = msoLineStylePreset20
  End If
 Next i
 End Sub
```

Could Anyone light in solving This ?

Best Regards
Polos

Comment: Any solution regarding this cause I'm really blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub fzerfgsdf()
    '
    ' fzerfgsdf Macro
    '
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim chrt As Excel.Chart
    Dim sries As Excel.Series
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim clLeft As Double, clTop As Double
    Dim clWidth As Double, clHeight As Double
    Dim clBeginX As Double, clBeginY As Double, clEndX As Double, clEndY As Double
    Dim cl As Excel.Point
    Dim shpOval As Excel.Shape
    Dim dl As Excel.DataLabel
    Dim i As Long

    clHeight = 30
    clWidth = 15

    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
    Set chrt = ws.ChartObjects("Graphique 69").Chart
    Set sries = chrt.SeriesCollection(1)
    x = sries.Values
    For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
        Debug.Print "Point "; i; "="; x(i)
        If (x(i) < 1) And (x(i) <> 0) Then
            Set cl = sries.Points(i)
            With chrt.ChartArea
                clBeginX = IIf(.Left + cl.Left - clWidth < 0, 0, .Left + cl.Left - clWidth)
                clBeginY = IIf(.Top + cl.Top - clHeight < 0, 0, .Top + cl.Top - clHeight)
                clEndX = .Left + cl.Left
                clEndY = .Top + cl.Top
            End With

            Set shpOval = ws.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, clBeginX, clBeginY, clEndX, clEndY)
            shpOval.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadOpen
            shpOval.ShapeStyle = msoLineStylePreset20

            cl.HasDataLabel = True
            sries.HasLeaderLines = False
            Set dl = cl.DataLabel
            With dl
                .Text = "RFT 93%=> 5P"
                .Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
                .Format.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangularCallout
                .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
                .Top = cl.Top - clHeight - .Height - 5
                .Left = cl.Left - clWidth - (.Width / 2)
                With .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
                    .Size = 12
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    .Bold = msoTrue
                End With
            End With
        End If
    Next

    Set shpOval = Nothing
    Set cl = Nothing
    Set sries = Nothing
    Set chrt = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this but it says Variable or object not defined  error  in this line " ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i)"

Comment: What is the error code? Also, is the error on this line `Set cl = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i)`, or is there a different line now with just `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i)`?

Comment: error is all  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i)  see link https://i.postimg.cc/W19j1t1j/bcda.png

Comment: both lines in blue

Comment: It sounds like you may have made a change to the chart, which introduced a new error. Apparently this part of your code still works: `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values`, which means the problem is not with the portion `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)`. It seems to be specific to the part that calls `.Points(i)`. Are there still points in the chart?

Comment: What is the value of `i` in `Point(i)` when you get the error? Also, what is the exact error code (i.e. error number)?

Comment: There is no error but It's not pointing to the head of that highlighted Chart in that image red circle ......the problem that when the x(i) is <1 then an arrow is created and go the right chart then point the right position like that image

Comment: So you're saying there is no error now, but there is still a problem with the way the arrows are being drawn. Are all of the arrows converging at one point (i.e. 579, 131.25)?

Comment: yes and I need them to move according to the graph where x(i) <1

Comment: can I ask  when Last question ? it worked perfectly and i will accept it  but is there away that I can add text to that arrow  for e.g the  the arrow is pointing and  says a specific text https://i.postimg.cc/6q19XJnB/3212.png

Comment: Great, I'm glad it worked for you! Please go ahead and accept the answer since it answers the scope of your original problem, and I'll see what I can find about labels.

Comment: Any news Ken ? *

Comment: ken I get an error in this line    .Position = xlLabelPositionAbove

Comment: You can comment-out or delete the line `.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove`. It gets overridden later when setting `.Top`.